# I'm looking for a short story about a sculptor who creates a hand and is strangled by it

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I believe I read the story approximately 10 years ago in a US newspaper online when looking for information on H.P.Lovecraft. I don't recall the newspaper or the year I read it, but I believe it was from the late 1930s or early 1940s. Even though the story seems to be Lovecraftian I don't believe Lovecraft wrote the tale since I would have noticed it.

The plot revolved around a sculptor who was obsessed with the human body and who lived near a graveyard. He made a large hand using earth collected from the cemetery. The hand looked lifelike. He displayed his work in his studio and asked some of his friends and colleagues to admire it.

One night, the hand came to life and crawling off its pedestal went upstairs towards the sculptor's bed, where he was sleeping. The hand grabbed his neck and choked him to death. Then, the hand went down the stairs dragging the body.

The narrative concludes when the sculptor's friends came to visit him and discovered the sculptor's lifeless body, his hand wrapped around his throat. The sculptor's friends shrieked and fled.

**EDIT:**

I just found this link about Lovecraft's ideas for possible future use in weird fiction presented to R. H. Barlow on May 7, 1934 in exchange for an admirably neat, typed copy from his skilled hand. Idea #7 says:

> Horror Story: The sculptured hand - or other artificial hand -which strangles its creator.

I'm not sure if the above is really true. Also, I don't have the reference to the original document/letter/manuscript mentioned in the link but at least this tells me that Lovecraft himself or Barlow or someone else could have used it to write the tale.

https://suptg.thisisnotatrueending.com/archive/2009/5889042/

I found the related entry in Lovecraft wiki fandom. The plot idea of the sculpted killer hand is contained in what is called the Lovecraft's Commonplace Book.

https://lovecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commonplace_Book